# Lenovo Yoga Wifi not working

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 13 and wifi is not working. I have tried installing driver rtl8723au but when running

```
sudo modprobe 8723au
```

I get an error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8723au': Device or resource busy
```

Outputs of the following commands:

```
makosz@makoszlap:~$ uname -a
Linux makoszlap 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

makosz@makoszlap:~$ lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:0153] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [17aa:3977]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e56] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [17aa:3977]
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [17aa:3977]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller [8086:1e24] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller [17aa:3977]


makosz@makoszlap:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b322 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments Invensense Embedded MotionApp HID Sensor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:000a Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8723AU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13b1:0020 Linksys WUSB54GC v1 802.11g Adapter [Ralink RT73]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

makosz@makoszlap:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx0018390e2898  IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"SBG6700AC-EB684"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 1C:49:7B:91:08:3A   
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:176   Missed beacon:0

wlx24fd520d9ef3  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off


makosz@makoszlap:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    16384  1
ccm                    20480  1
rt73usb                32768  0
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt73usb
rt2x00lib              57344  2 rt73usb,rt2x00usb
crc_itu_t              16384  1 rt73usb
rfcomm                 69632  0
input_leds             16384  0
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
r8723au               516096  0
arc4                   16384  4
bnep                   20480  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
jitterentropy_rng      16384  0
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
drbg                   32768  1
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
ansi_cprng             16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
dm_crypt               28672  1
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm                   536576  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
rtl8xxxu               73728  0
aesni_intel           167936  2159
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
uvcvideo               90112  0
mac80211              737280  3 rtl8xxxu,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  1080 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
btusb                  45056  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
joydev                 20480  0
btintel                16384  1 btusb
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  0
cfg80211              565248  3 mac80211,rt2x00lib,r8723au
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  10  hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  6 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
hid_multitouch         20480  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd                    81920  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq, snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei_me                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
acpi_als               16384  0
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
kfifo_buf              16384  2 industrialio_triggered_buffer,acpi_als
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
industrialio           57344  9 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,acpi_als,hid_sensor_rotation,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_magn_3d
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_sensor_custom      20480  0
hid_sensor_hub         20480  8 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  6 hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
i915                 1208320  3
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
drm                   360448  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop
fjes                   28672  0
```

Note that I am using an external usb wifi card to connect to the internet currently, but ran sudo modprobe 8723au when it was unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

followed directions in [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262693). I dont know what helped as when I went to sleep it still didn't work but woke up and somehow works now.